# Why does my sub-query work with a string, but not a field reference?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have (what I think is) a rather complex query. The query gets the record that I want and then all of the data referenced in the first response. It works if my sub-query conditional is a string, but not if it's a field (of the exact same value).

```sql
// Query with string as conditional in lowest sub-query (4th line from the bottom)

SELECT 
     e1.entity as entity
    ,ARRAY_CAT(
      ARRAY_COMPACT( 
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT( 
          any_value(e2.entity), 
          any_value(u1.user) 
        )
      )
      ,ARRAY_AGG(e3.entity)
    ) as includes
FROM ENTITIES e1
LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e2 ON e1.entity:owner:workspace = e2.entity:id
LEFT JOIN USERS u1 ON e1.entity:owner:user = u1.user:id
LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e3 ON e3.entity:id IN (
  SELECT ee2.value FROM 
  table(FLATTEN( input=> 
    SELECT SPLIT(LISTAGG( CASE WHEN IS_ARRAY(ee1.value:id) THEN ARRAY_TO_STRING(ee1.value:id, ',') ELSE ee1.value:id END, ','), ',') 
    FROM table(FLATTEN( input => ( SELECT e4.entity:relationships:entities FROM ENTITIES e4 WHERE e4.entity:id = 'bd265f29-ca32-449a-b765-bb488e4d6b3c' ) )) ee1
  )) ee2
)
GROUP BY e1.entity
```

The above produces:

"entity" column:
https://jsonblob.com/6d98b587-8989-11e9-b738-a9487a0dac0b

"includes" column:
https://jsonblob.com/068a8672-8988-11e9-b738-77f0e471310b

However, if I change the uuid string (`bd265f29-ca32-449a-b765-bb488e4d6b3c`) to `e1.entity:id` (below) then I get the error `SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`.

```sql
SELECT 
     e1.entity as entity
    ,ARRAY_CAT(
      ARRAY_COMPACT( 
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT( 
          any_value(e2.entity), 
          any_value(u1.user) 
        )
      )
      ,ARRAY_AGG(e3.entity)
    ) as includes
FROM ENTITIES e1
LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e2 ON e1.entity:owner:workspace = e2.entity:id
LEFT JOIN USERS u1 ON e1.entity:owner:user = u1.user:id
LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e3 ON e3.entity:id IN (
  SELECT ee2.value FROM 
  table(FLATTEN( input=> 
    SELECT SPLIT(LISTAGG( CASE WHEN IS_ARRAY(ee1.value:id) THEN ARRAY_TO_STRING(ee1.value:id, ',') ELSE ee1.value:id END, ','), ',') 
    FROM table(FLATTEN( input => ( SELECT e4.entity:relationships:entities FROM ENTITIES e4 WHERE e4.entity:id = e1.entity:id ) )) ee1
  )) ee2
)
GROUP BY e1.entity
```

I have no idea why the switch is causing the error. Why does my sub-query work with a string, but not a field reference?

Comment: In the first left join you have: LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e2 ON e1.entity:owner:workspace = e2.entity:id
Should it be "Where e4.entity:id = e1.entity:owner:workspace"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with a couple of CTE's to provide data, when can do most of the lifting of your correlated sub-queries. I put both forms of arrays of things in entities, and a single entity with multiple id's as is expressed in your FLATTEN usage:

```
WITH users AS (
    SELECT parse_json('{"id":1}') as user
), entities AS (
    SELECT parse_json(column1) as entity 
    FROM VALUES
        ('{"id":10, "relationships":{"entities":[{"id":11},{"id":12}]}, "owner":{"user":1,"workspace":10}}'),
        ('{"id":11, "relationships":{"entities":[{"id":11}]}}'),
        ('{"id":12, "relationships":{"entities":[{"id":[10,11]}]}}')
), ent1 AS (
    SELECT e4.entity:id as ent_id
        ,ee1.index
        ,SPLIT(LISTAGG( IFF( IS_ARRAY(ee1.value:id), ARRAY_TO_STRING(ee1.value:id, ','), ee1.value:id), ','), ',') as vals
    FROM ENTITIES AS e4, 
    TABLE(FLATTEN( input => e4.entity:relationships:entities )) ee1
    GROUP BY 1,2
), ent_rels AS (
    SELECT ent_id, ee2.value::number as rel_id
    FROM ent1 ee1,
    TABLE(FLATTEN( input => ee1.vals)) ee2
)
SELECT 
    e1.entity:id as entity
    ,e2.entity:id as e2_entity
    ,u1.user:id as u1_user
    ,e3.entity:id as e3_entity
FROM ENTITIES e1
LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e2 ON e1.entity:owner:workspace = e2.entity:id
LEFT JOIN USERS u1 ON e1.entity:owner:user = u1.user:id
LEFT JOIN ent_rels er ON er.ent_id = e1.entity:id
LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e3 ON e3.entity:id = er.rel_id
ORDER BY e1.entity:id;
```

So this SQL is not the select results you had, but does shown things are JOINING as expected.

```
ENTITY    E2_ENTITY    U1_USER    E3_ENTITY
10        10           1          11
10        10           1          12
11        null         null       11
12        null         null       10
12        null         null       11
```

So this final select is the way you had it originally

```
SELECT 
     e1.entity as entity
    ,ARRAY_CAT(
      ARRAY_COMPACT( 
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT( 
          any_value(e2.entity), 
          any_value(u1.user) 
        )
      )
      ,ARRAY_AGG(e3.entity)
    ) as includes
FROM ENTITIES e1
LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e2 ON e1.entity:owner:workspace = e2.entity:id
LEFT JOIN USERS u1 ON e1.entity:owner:user = u1.user:id
LEFT JOIN ent_rels er ON er.ent_id = e1.entity:id
LEFT JOIN ENTITIES e3 ON e3.entity:id = er.rel_id
GROUP BY e1.entity
ORDER BY e1.entity:id;
```

Also given the fact you are undoing two layers of nesting to get matching id's, you can avoid the LISTAGG and SPLITS and just break them up via:

```
), ent1 AS (
    SELECT e4.entity:id as ent_id
        ,ee1.value:id as vals
    FROM ENTITIES AS e4, 
    TABLE(FLATTEN( input => e4.entity:relationships:entities )) ee1

), ent_rels AS (
    SELECT ent_id
        ,coalesce(ee2.value,ee1.vals) as rel_id
    FROM ent1 ee1,
    TABLE(FLATTEN( input => ee1.vals, outer => true)) ee2
)
```

which can be merged/nested if that's your preference:

```
, ent_rels AS (
    SELECT ent_id
        ,coalesce(ee3.value,ee2.vals) as rel_id
    FROM (
      SELECT e1.entity:id as ent_id
        ,ee1.value:id as vals
        FROM ENTITIES AS e1, 
        TABLE(FLATTEN( input => e1.entity:relationships:entities )) ee1
    ) ee2,
    TABLE(FLATTEN( input => ee2.vals, outer => true)) ee3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html) on subqueries includes this restriction:

> Correlated scalar subqueries are currently supported only if they can be statically determined to return one row (e.g. if the SELECT list contains an aggregate function with no GROUP BY).

So you might try:

```
( SELECT MAX(e4.entity:relationships:entities)
  FROM ENTITIES e4
  WHERE e4.entity:id = e1.entity:id
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work and returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cast it like this?

```
e1.entity:id::string
```

Comment: Yes, I have. I'm comparing e1.entity:id to itself in a different join result, so casting shouldn't be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake documentation mentions:

> Subqueries with a correlation inside of FLATTEN are currently
>   unsupported.

Can you not simply use e1.entity:relationships:entities instead of the subquery?

Comment: No, because relationships is being filtered down to a smaller set.